# package inheritance in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to do package inheritance in python i.e. say Package A has modules mod1, mod2 and some other subpackages. Now Package B should inherit all the modules and subpackages from A such that it should be possible to do `import B.mod1`.

I have gone through package inheritance section in the following link  http://peak.telecommunity.com/doc/src/peak/config/modules.html, but was unable to `import peak.api`. I have also tried importing all the modules of the parent package in the `__init__` file of child package, but it did not help.

Comment: It's somewhat messy, but would `from B import *` work? This would add `mod1`, `mod2` and so on with the names `mod1` and `mod2` rather than `B.mod1` and `B.mod2`.

Comment: star imports should only be used as a convenient shortcut in the python shell. Using them in modules makes is a good receipe for unmaintainable code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers they are sometimes -- carefully -- used in just this situation, if you just want to copy somebody else's namespace into yours.

Comment: @katrielalex: I know they are sometimes used - and some packages even "recommend" doing so - but *everytime* I've seen this it led to maintenance problems one day or another. Explicit is better than implicit...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It's used in `numpy`.

Answer (score 4):

```
# package B __init__.py
from A import mod1, mod2, modN
```

And that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. All you have to do is declare `__all__` variable in `__init__` which should contain all modules you'd like to expose. See [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See for example the source code to `numpy`'s `__init__.py` (Python 2.7) :

```
import core
from core import *
import compat
import lib
from lib import *
import linalg
import fft
import polynomial
import random
import ctypeslib
import ma
import matrixlib as _mat
from matrixlib import *

# Make these accessible from numpy name-space
#  but not imported in from numpy import *
from __builtin__ import bool, int, long, float, complex, \
     object, unicode, str
from core import round, abs, max, min

__all__.extend(['__version__', 'pkgload', 'PackageLoader',
           'show_config'])
__all__.extend(core.__all__)
__all__.extend(_mat.__all__)
__all__.extend(lib.__all__)
__all__.extend(['linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma'])
```